# UILabel text alignment only working in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel

I've created a custom cell with several UILabels and everything works great, but for some reason I can't seem to get the text in any of my labels to do anything other than center.

Everything was created in Storyboard, and I set the left-alignment attribute, it looks perfect in the simulator, but when I test my code on my iPhone, all the labels center.

Since it's all in Storyboard, there isn't really any code snippet I can share, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Also clean your project and build folder.  Sometimes junk gets left behind....

Comment: Make sure that the simulator is emulating your specific device.

Comment: Thanks.  It turned out that autolayout was changing the size of the Labels in my cell, turning that off seems to have resolved the issue for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that autolayout was changing the size of the Labels in my cell, turning that off seems to have resolved the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

Did You remove app from device ? sometimes when adding/testing style features, old style is appended, until You delete the app.

Answer (score 0):

Do one or both of the following:

1. Remove the app from your device and re-build it onto the device
2. Remove the folders in the DerivedData associated with your app. By default, the DerivedData folder is is located at /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

This usually fixes all the Ui-related issues I've come across.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it looks like auto layout was messing me up, but I'm socking this one away for future issues I come across.

Comment: No problem! Mind upvoting this answer, since your own response was the correct response?

Comment: I wish I could, I don't have enough rep to do so.